# Beginner JavaScript isNaN issues?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, nan

```
function IsValid(value){
    var valid = true;

    if (isNaN(value) || value == ""){
        valid = false;
    }

    return value;
}
```

Beginner at JavaScript so I'm sure this will be an easy question. We are using the above function to check the parameters and generate an error message.  It works fine EXCEPT FOR the "isNaN" part of it.

```
    if (IsValid(wind)) {
        wind = parseFloat(wind);

        if (wind < MIN_WIND || wind > MAX_WIND) {
            SetError("divWindError", "Wind must be between " + MIN_WIND +
            " and " + MAX_WIND);
            return;
        }
    } else {
        SetError("divWindError", "Wind is not valid");
        return;
    }
```

Comment: What's the value of `wind`?

Comment: return `valid` instead of `value`.

Comment: there is no reason to downvote.  This is a perfectly reasonable question and users shouldn't be discouraged from asking things like this.

Comment: @Melissa, don't forget to accept the response you think best answers the question, it helps community members referencing this thread for similar problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things.  First, you're returning the wrong value, second, your check should be updated to include `null` and `undefined` checks as well:

```
function IsValid(value){
    var valid = true;

    if (!value || isNaN(value)){ // updated check to include NaN, "", undefined, and null
        valid = false;
    }

    return valid; // correct return value is valid, not value
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function IsValid(value){
    var valid = true;

    if (isNaN(value) || value == ""){
        valid = false;
    }

    return valid; // you needed to return valid not the value
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Always something simple.